# Time Format Problem: Comparison is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, time

MYSQL

Format of time in two tables:-

```
Jan 1 2018 10:42:06
```

table1.time greater than table2.time

Comparison is not working in these tables

```
table1.time > table2.time
```

No data is coming

Comment: You're going to have to give us more to work on.. Table structures, command you're running, expected results .. etc.

Comment: Post the output of a describe table <x> or show create table <x> command, and what your exact query command is, for example : select * from table 1 where table1.time > table2.time .. then show us an example of the data result you expect

Comment: For comparing two tables you might need to add joins

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1 AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS b ON a.id = b.id WHERE CAST(a.time as datetime) > CAST(b.time as datetime)` Something like this can help

Comment: Add some sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And show us your current query attempt. BTW, which dbms are you using?

Comment: Are the columns `time` Date or string columns?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for :

```
STR_TO_DATE(a.time, '%b %d %Y %H:%i:%d')
```

The [mysql STR_TO_DATE function](http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date) lets you translate strings to date.

Once strings are converted to date, you can compare them using the < operator or the-like